# How to remove the first character from a string if it's a non-number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a text field on a form that allows individuals to enter a price. I'm trying to allow other currency symbols to be entered into this field but my logic behind the scenes needs to strip out any currency symbols.

To make it easier, I really only care about the first character and only if it's a non number.

Otherwise, I can't use a solution that would remove any decimal points or commas in my price field or my calculations won't work.

Update: I'm currently using
itemCost = itemCost.replace(/\$/, '');

But now I'm trying to open it up to any currency sign.

Comment: Be aware that you can't necessarily guarantee that the currency "symbol" will either be a single character or be at the start of the string. See https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/22589 for more info

Comment: Create a small input to the left of your number input to enter currency, So you have the granularity you want.

Comment: Why not generalise this and simply remove *everything but digits and periods* / pick out the number from the string? `price.match(/[0-9.]+/)`

Comment: This would strip any leading non-digits, but consider the issues mentioned in the previous comments `var noLeadingDigits  = str.replace( /^\D+/g, ''); `

Answer (score 2):

You can access a string in the same way as you would an array. Take a look at the character at position zero of the string -

```
var inputString = '...' // whatever the user entered
var firstChar = inputString[0];
if (!Number.isInteger(firstChar)) {
    inputString = inputString.substr(1)
}
```

I'm using the [`String.subStr` function here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to create a copy of the string starting from the 1st index.

Please take into consideration though that solution assumes that the provided string will **only ever** have one currency symbol. Inputs such as "USD $1.00" or even " $1.00" will not work with this solution.

---

An alternative would be to remove any character that is non numeric (excluding decimal points and commas) from the entire input string.

```
var inputString = '...' // whatever the user entered
var priceString = inputString.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/, '')

// $1.00 -> 1.00
// USD #$1,000.00 -> 1,000.00
```

Comment: Nice solution but that would also accept 08/23/2017 or 7:45

Comment: @Salketer - true. However the original question was not asking to validate if  the provided input is a valid price :) I suppose that if a user entered their phone number into a price field there would be some unexpected behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you whitelist  characters instead?

```
'$99,99'.match(/[0-9]+[,.]{0,1}[0-9]*/)
```

You'll certainly want to perfect it, I wrote it fast...

What the suggested regex does is make sure we have one or more digits, then maybe either a `,` or a `.` and 0 or more digits.

What I mostly want to point out with this answer is, while keeping just numeric characters is easy, it will by no mean make certain that the user entered a correct currency. The is also no way to know if the user entering `1,337` meant `1,337.00` or `1.337`

Comment: Can we get an explanation of exactly what this does?

Comment: `/[0-9,]+\.[0-9,]*/` It's maybe more accurate, to accept numbers like `123.456,789` for example

Comment: you are right, but it's even more complicated than just that. You need to consider that thousand separators can be spaces or commas. But decimal separators can be commas or dot... And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

`parseInt()` parses a string and returns an integer.

If the *first character cannot be converted to a number*, `parseInt()` returns `NaN`.

```
parseInt('Hello') // returns NaN
```

Also it's a good idea to `trim()` the string before using `parseInt()`

```js
var money = '$123.45';

if( money ) { // check if variable is not null
money = money.trim();
}


console.log(parseInt(money));
// check NaN using isNaN function
if(isNaN(parseInt(money))) {
 console.log('first charatcer is not a number')
 money = money.substr(1);
 console.log(money);
}
else {
console.log('first charatcer is a number')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Javscript function could be

// Function to check first letter as numbers

```
function chkNumeric(inputtxt)  
{

 var letterNumber = '^[0-9]{1,}[ a-zA-Z0-9]*$';  

 if((inputtxt.value.match(letterNumber))   
  {  

   return true;  

  }  

else  

  {   
   return false;   

  }  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this... One way is to make the input into an array, check isNaN on the first element, and strip it if it's not a number.

```
const input = '$123.45';
const otherInput = '23.34';


function splitCheck(someInput) {
  let arrayInput = someInput.split('');
  if (isNaN(arrayInput[0])) {
      arrayInput.shift();
      return arrayInput.join('');
  } else {
      return someInput;
  }
}

splitCheck(input); // returns 123.45
splitCheck(otherInput); // returns 23.34
```

Note you can also use a regexp, or you can also check for ASCII character values across an array, but this is just the first that came to mind.